# Remove type from union or use a null union in array.filter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a variable declared as:

```
public filter: string | null;
```

I try to use it in a filter array function which returns an error:

```
 Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
 Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

I want to, preferably temporarily or in the current scope either remove the null union from the filter variable so I can use array functions. Or in any other way. Any help?

```
  refined.filter(a => a.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.filter => ); //error at "this.filter"
```

Comment: Why is `null` in there to begin with, if it can't be `null`? You can check for non-null: `if (filter !== null) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: May you share the code which produces this error?

Comment: Updated with example. @ASDFGerte The variable is public/global and can only be non-null in specific scope/functions.If-check will not work as its not the value,  but the type the tslint complains about.

Comment: You can also use the non-null-assertion operator in the spots you use it, use an assertion function, cast, use a user-defined typeguard, or the above-mentioned. And yes, flow-analysis will understand a check for null, so it will narrow to `string`, if you check. See [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#equality-narrowing). Also it's hopefully tsc (or ts-server), not tslint, that is complaining.

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If seems like there's no point in running the filtering function if `filter === null`, right?

In that case, you should condition the expression and return an appropriate value:

```js
if (filter)
    // TypeScript knows that inside your `if` statement, `this.filter` is never null
    return refined.filter(a => a.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.filter));

return null; // or anything else
```

You could make this into a ternary expression:

```js
return filter ? refined.filter(a => a.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.filter)) : null;
```